# how to move buffer position in vimscript

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'm trying to use an autocmd to check for the existence of a certain file when a file is opened. If the file exists, I want to do a `vsplit`, and move the vsplit buffer to the right. Something like:

```
function! CheckForFile()
    let file=expand("%:p:h")."/.".expand("%:t").".x"
    if filereadable(file)
        execute "vs " . file
        <C-w>L
   endif
endfunction
autocmd BufReadPost * call CheckForFile()
```

I can't figure out how to do the `<C-w>L` part. All I get is syntax errors.

How do I move the buffer in the CheckForFile function?

Comment: I feel like this could be an annoying feature. There is a bunch of work that needs to be here to make this snippet work. Wouldn't a nice command or a mapping be a better option than an autocommand? If you are dead set please look at `:h <afile>` and`:h :rightb`. You are also needlessly using `expand()` and you should use `:normal!` to execute normal commands.

Comment: yes, potentially annoying, but I'd only explicitly turn it on in certain situations.

Comment: how do you use it without expand? I can't do `let file=%:p:h/.%:t.x` as that gives syntax errors, and `let file="%:p:h/.%:t.x"` with quotes simply yields the quoted string with no expansion.

Comment: using `execute "rightb vs ". file` worked great! but adding `normal! <C-w>h` doesn't do anything though

Comment: You have 2 `expand()`'s that are not really doing anything productive. You should need just the following `let file = expand('%:p') . '.x'` or better yet do pass in `expand('<afile>')` into your function. Use something like `windcmd p` or `windcmd h`. This is far too much information for a comment and I don't feel like posting an answer. I really just wanted you to think about creating a command as I felt like it would be less invasive.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. It is very very appreciated.

Comment: I'm using two expands because I'm prepending a `.` to the basename of the file. Otherwise, yes, `%:p` would have worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<C-w>L
```

is a normal mode command; as such, it can't be used *as is* in the context of a function. The equivalent ex command of all the `<C-w>` normal mode command is `wincmd {char}` as you can see at the end of `:help window-move-cursor`.

So the correct notation is:

```
wincmd L
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for this situation. In other cases where you need to use a normal mode command from a script you can use the `:normal` command. (You could use it here too, but it's roundabout given the existence of `wincmd`.) You'd need a literal ctrl-W, or you can use it with `exe` and say something like `exe "normal \<c-w>L"` (the `\<c-w>` inside double-quotes will be turned into a ctrl-W for you by vimscript.)

Comment: thanks! I didn't know about the escaping of `<c-...>` in double quotes